# Proving that if $(a,b)=1$, then $(a, b+1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

#### Problem

If $(a,b)=1$ then  $(a, b+1)=1$.

#### Progress

So far I have,

- Let $d = (a,b)$
- Which implies $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$
- Which implies there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $d\mid (a)(x) + (b)(y)$
- So I want to find an $x$ and $y$ that can make the equation, $ax+by$ into $(a+1)(x)+(ab)(y)$

Comment: what if you let $a = 5$ and $b = 6$?

Comment: I don't think that the statement is true. Try $a =2$ and $b = 3$. Then $(2,3) = 1$ but $(2+1, 2\times3) = (3,6) = 3$. Am I missing something?

Comment: What about $(6,7)=1$ while $(7,42)=7$? (well, I was too late...)

Comment: Maybe you mean $(a+b,ab)=1$ in the conclusion?

Comment: Anna: I edited your question. I tried to make the formatting more like what I think you had intended it to be.

Comment: what i mean is you square it and then you get a^2*x^2 + 2abxy +b^2y^2 and continue to manipulate it

Comment: @Anna: As has been pointed out, there are $b$ for which the assertion is false, so one cannot hope to prove it in general. Perhaps you did not quote the question exactly as it was posed.

Answer (score 5):

if $b=a+1$ then the second gcd is $a+1$

Comment: what i mean is you square it and then you get a^2*x^2 + 2abxy +b^2y^2 and continue to manipulate it

Comment: @Anna, the statement you are trying to prove is false. At this point, you should go back and check the source of the problem very carefully.

Comment: Anna = Cindy?${}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, she changed it not long after I wrote this answer. I'm pretty sure she had time to see this. And, she has gone on to ask a bunch of questions at this level. I don't think she  pays much attention after she posts things...I get it, also unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives $u,v$ with $abu+(a+b)v=1$, given $ax+by=1$.

Start with $ax=1-by$, subtract $ay$ from both sides, and get
$$a(x-y)=1-(a+b)y.$$
Now start with $by=1-ax$, subtract $bx$ from both sides, and get
$$b(y-x)=1-(a+b)x.$$
Now multiply these equations to get
$$ab(x-y)(y-x)=1-(a+b)x -(a+b)y + (a+b)^2 xy,$$
which may be rearranged as
$$ab(x-y)(y-x)+(a+b)(x+y-(a+b)xy)=1.$$
With $u=(x-y)(y-x)$ and $v=x+y-(a+b)xy$ this is $abu+(a+b)v=1.$